# Не обновляются JS скрипты при нажатии F5 в Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Походу не один я столкнулся с такой проблемой, но ответ в гугле найти не могу. Вообщем суть такая, сохраняю я код скрипта js, нажимаю f5 и f12->sources, в итоге скрипты не обновляются. Объясните, как избавится от этой дряни, не перестать же мне пользоваться хромом или перезапускать браузер ради мелочи.

Comment: чисти кэш есть даже плагины для хрома

Comment: Нажмите `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в DevTools на вкладке Network установить флажок Disable cache.

Comment: Будет работать только при открытой консоли разработчика.

Comment: @Other, для разработки самое то.

Comment: Ну не всегда это удобно.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в браузерах скрипты и css кешируются.. Поэтому при обновлении страницы так как файл не менялся (тоесть его имя) то может загружаться файл из кеша... Иногда помогает shift+ctrl+r , но бывает и этого недостаточно, поэтому для того что бы браузер понял, что нужно обновить скрипт иногда применяют следующий прием:

```
<script src="js/table_creator.js?version={version}"></script>
```

где после каждого изменения скрипта меняют  часть адреса после знака "?". Аналогичная ситуация может происходить и  со стилями.
Хром в этом отношении  особо трудно избавить от кеша,   тоесть  например, как я выше написал shift+ctrl+r должен перезагружать страницу без кеша, но..  этого мало. для обычного пользователя кеширование должно быть .. оно ускоряет повторную загрузку ресурсов-- шрифтов, ну и всего вышеперечисленного. Для разработчика наоборот нужны актуальные скрипты... хотя даже для пользователя, если,  например,  сервис обновил скрипты,  нужны актуальные. поэтому  в пути к файлу указывают например время создания файла или его хеш (кто на что горазд). но важно что   бы менялось это значение только при изменении файла.

Например в исходном коде VK скрипты следующего вида

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cmodules/web/page_layout.js?1172409392">
```

Со стилями у них аналогично:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/al/common.css?32352845315" />
```

Comment: Можно через php дописывать после имени файла текущий time stamp. <? echo "<script src='script.js?".time()."'></script>";?>

Comment: да.. для разработки пойдет.. на проде так не желательно, потому что каждая загрузка будет заново генерировать time и значит загружать  заново js  вместо кеша.